# MySQL limiting by foreign key

Tags: mysql, database, join, enums, foreign-keys

I have a complex object I'm trying to store in the database.

I feel that for every case where I'd like to limit possible values, I should store values on a table and have a foreign key constraint. I have a feeling this would be more flexible than having ENUM.

The problem is that there a lot of cases where I'd like to restrict values. (the data branches out as well and there are cases where I'd join a table in different places)

So I'd have to join every time I'd get a currency value, a unit of measurement, etc - exponentially increasing the number of joins.

What are your suggestions for this?

**Edit:**

There are probably 15-20 different types of joins I could use, some 3 levels deep

Comment: How do you get an exponential increase? It seems to me that you'd at most get a factor of 2 increase. Or was that just a figure of speech?

Comment: @Mark - Figure of speech -- I'm currently trying to do a rough count of how many joins I'd have to do if that helps any.

Answer (score 1):

I see three possible methods of implementing the constraints:

A case could be made to store any true [categorical variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_variable) in a separate table and have a Foreign Key pointing to that table whenever referenced. That can help keep the database cleaner and easier to maintain in many cases. Knowing that your users' "State" attribute is a numerical variable between 1 and 50, rather than a string which may be "MA", "ma", "Mass.", or "Massachusetts" will certainly keep your DBAs (and developers and, thus, end-users) happy.

However, if your variable isn't truly categorical, but has some specific criteria about it, you could impose them using [CHECK constraints](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp) (MySQL details [here](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/Triggers#Emulating_Check_Constraints)). These allow you to define a certain range of valid values without having to enumerate each possible one, which may be helpful if you just want to check the validity on insert without incurring the penalty of a Foreign Key lookup.

Finally, there's certainly a place for constraints imposed in the business logic. I find that complex constraints (regex matching, etc.) are best maintained in application code rather than a SQL database.

Note that a foreign key won't necessarily be detrimental to performance. You can run some tests, but I've found that performing a join on a large (500k rows) table to a small (20 rows) categorical table shows no noticeable impact on performance. So you're probably ok without worrying about it.

If you do have dozens of potential values you want to ENUM, keep in mind that the performance hit will only occur when you do the joins, which isn't always necessary. Often times for your data retrieval, you can make do just having the IDs, rather than the actual values. In this case, the existence of a Foreign Key in no way affects your SELECTS, and only incurs a minor penalty on each INSERT/UPDATE, as the system will need to check that the Foreign Key is valid.